# Trying to return size of input file of c++ but recieve an error when I convert the char variable to string

Tags: c++, string, file, input, count

I am trying to count the characters in my program. Initially my variable "words" was a char and the file read just fine. When trying to determine the length of the variable, it wouldn't work with `.length()`. Can you explain how I can make my "words" variable as a string so that the `words.length()` executes correctly?

error on line `words = readFile.get();` is:

**no match for ‘operator!=’ in ‘words != -0x00000000000000001’**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

//buff array to hold char words in the input text file
string words;

//char words;

//read file
ifstream readFile("TextFile1.txt");
//notify user if the file didn't transfer into the system
if (!readFile)
    cout <<"I am sorry but we could not process your file."<<endl;

//read and output the file
while (readFile)
{
    words = readFile.get();
    if(words!= EOF)
      cout <<words;
}

cout << "The size of the file is: " << words.length() << " bytes. \n";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you make any attempt to check the signature of get function...

Comment: Read e.g. [this `std::istream::get` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get).

Comment: Did you really need a string to count the number of characters. This certianly will not work the way you think. I mean even if get had the correct signature you replace the string each input of your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read some reference.. try [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) and look for [`std::instream::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get)

---

I'm not sure what do you want, but if you wanna just count words, you can do something like this:

```
std::ifstream InFile(/*filename*/);
if(!InFile)
    // file not found

std::string s;
int numWords = 0;

while(InFile >> s)
    numWords++;

std::cout << numWords;
```

---

Or if you want to get to know how many characters are in file, change `std::string s` to `char s` and use [`std::ifstream::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) instead:

```
std::ifstream InFile(/*filename*/);
if(!InFile)
    // file not found

char s;
int numCharacters = 0;

while(InFile.get(s)) //this will read one character after another until EOF
    numCharacters++;

std::cout << numCharacters;
```

The second approach is easier: 
If file uses [`ASCII`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), *numCharacters == fileSize;*
Otherwise if it uses [`UNICODE`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode), *numCharacters == fileSize / 2;*

Answer (score 1):

```
char c;
while (readFile.get(c))
{
    words.insert(c);
}
```

Of course, if you were solely doing this to count the number of characters (and were intent on using std::istream::get) you'd probably be better off just doing this:

```
int NumChars = 0;
while (readFile.get())
{
    NumChars++;
}
```

Oh, and by the way, you might want to close the file after you're done with it.

Answer (score 0):

get() returns an int, to do what you're doing, you must check that int before appending to "words" instead of checking words against EOF, e.g.:

```
...
//read and output the file
while (readFile)
{
    const int w = readFile.get();
    if (w!= EOF) {
      words += w;
      cout <<words;
    }
}
...
```